# Do I need to add a maven dependency explicitly, when I already get it through some other dependency?

Tags: java, maven

Consider following scenario,

I develop a maven artifact which depends on an artifact (Say dependency is `artifact_a`).

`artifact_a` also depends on some other artifact `artifact_b`. Both of them are not developed by me.

Now, I need to use functionality in `artifact_b` in my artifact too.

Even if I do not add dependency for `artifact_b` in my artifact pom, my artifact still builds successfully since I automatically get it through `artifact_a` dependency.

I have two options,

- Add `artifact_b` dependency explicitly. This will be redundant, and
  if I do not add the same version that is added in `artifact_a`, I do
  not know what will happen
- Do not add `artifact_b` dependency explicitly. If I do not add it
  explicitly, when I increase the version of `artifact_a`, new version
  may no longer depend on `artifact_b`, causing a build failure in my
  artifact. Also, if I have many dependencies, it can be difficult to
  find whether the dependency gets inherited through current
  dependencies.

Is there a recommendation for this? If not, what is the better way?

Comment: Maven handles transitive dependencies, usually correctly. If a dependency requires something else, obviously it's there, or the dependency couldn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

> Even if I do not add dependency for artifact_b in my artifact pom, my artifact still builds successfully since I automatically get it through artifact_a dependency.

This is actually the answer already. If it builds successfully, then I would imply that this is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Best test is to build the application. If it fails you need to add it :-)

You do not need to add it explicitly. All is inherited from the other pom(s). If not then your pom of `artifact_b` is not correct.